# How can I get GIMP to remember my brush on a per tool basis?

Tags: gimp

I'm using a Wacom tablet.  I want to use a thin brush for painting, and when I flip over to erase, I want a fat brush.  However brush are not switched when I switch tools.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do *Edit > Preferences > Tool Options*.

Then under "Paint options shared between tools", uncheck the *Brush* option.

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks.